# Deploying webservice without deploying into web server

Tags: webserver

I want to deploy a simple SOAP based web service without actually deploying into a Web server. I just need to send requests, get responses and parse them. Please let me know if anyone have any ideas on this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to test it **in development** environment?

Comment: If you want to send requests and get responses, *some* kind of web server is necessary.  It may be a web server installed locally, or even embedded in your IDE.  We can't know for certain because you haven't specified.  But as a web application the service needs to be on a web instance of some kind in order to execute.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy a SOAP-based web service, you need a web server to host it.  The choice of a web server is up to you, and may depend on how you implemented your web service.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I found answer for my question, It is possible to deploy webservice without deploying into any web server/application server. Java 6 onwards supports this feature.Here is the link to provide sample implementation: http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jax-ws/create-and-consume-web-service-using-jax-ws/

Comment: In that case, why don't you summarize your finding and answer your own question?

Comment: The link which I mentioned above provides the details for sample implementation. Basically Java 6 onwards provides EndPoint class which publish the webservice and WSDL will generate on the fly runtime.